# UITextField secureTextEntry displays weird word instead of black dots

Tags: ios, uitextfield

This is an old source code that I need to optimize. I ran into a problem that secureTextEntry doesn't display properly (See picture). SecureText is enabled through storyboard and there is nothing to do with ViewController.

[image]

Comment: Are you using some custom font in your app?

Comment: Yes, my app uses a custom font

Comment: It would seem that your custom font has that special `ą́` character where there is normally has the block dot (bullet).